# App.config pointer to another .config with settings

Tags: c#, wpf, file, app-config

I want to use the standard App.config to point to the other .config files with specific settings. My knowledge is like 0% - i just read something about . But i dont know how to use it in my other .config files.

Example:
*App.config:*

`<configuration>
    <connectionString configSource="anotherConfig.config"/>
</configuration>`

*anotherConfig.config:*

How to do? i want a setting like

```
<userSettings>
    <setting name="Server" serializeAs="String">
        <value>localhost</value>
    </settings>
</userSettings>
```